# Is it possible to delete the content of specific rows by a macro in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have two spreadsheets, one is called "Input data" and the other is called "Assignment". If a value/content(in my case a name) in column C of "Assignment" does not occur in column C of "Input data", the specific row gets deleted by this formula that works completely fine:

```
function checkName() {


  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Input Data");
  var col1 = s1.getRange("C3:C").getValues();

  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Assignment");
  var col2 = s2.getRange("C4:C").getValues();

  for (var i=col2.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    var found = false;
    for (var j=0; j<col1.length; j++) {
       if (col1[j][0] == col2[i][0]) {
         found = true;
         break;
       }
    }

    if (!found) {
      s2.deleteRow(i+4);
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to delete only the contents of these specific rows or to delete only the content in specific columns of these specific rows? Like only column A-F of row 30 for example (if it fits to the criteria that I have described above). I tried `s2.deleteContents(i+4)` but that does not really work... Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When the values of "C4:C" in the sheet of "Assignment" are not found in the values of "C3:C" in the sheet of "Input Data", you want to clear the content of the row of column "A" to "F" for the sheet of "Assignment".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, your script was modified. Please modify your script as follows.

#### Modified script

From:

```
s2.deleteRow(i+4);
```

To:

```
s2.getRange(i+4, 1, 1, 6).clearContent();
```

- In this case, the content of the column "A" to "F" the row is cleared.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, at first, the ranges for clearing are retrieved. And the range list is cleared by `clearContent()`. The process cost might be able to be reduced a little.

#### Modified script

```
function checkName() {
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Input Data");
  var col1 = s1.getRange("C3:C" + s1.getLastRow()).getValues().map(function(e) {return e[0]});
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Assignment");
  var col2Range = s2.getRange("A4:F" + s2.getLastRow());
  var rangeList = col2Range.getValues().reduce(function(ar, e, i) {
    if (col1.indexOf(e[2]) == -1) ar.push("A" + (i + 4) + ":F" + (i + 4));
    return ar;
  }, []);
  // if (rangeList.length > 0) rangeList.push("A30:F30");
  s2.getRangeList(rangeList).clearContent();
}
```

- About `Like only column A-F of row 30 for example`, if you want to also clear the content of "A30:F30", please remove `//` of the line of `// if (rangeList.length > 0) rangeList.push("A30:F30");`. By this, when above condition occurs, the content of "A30:F30" is also cleared. But about this, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your goal. I apologize for this.

### References:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent)
- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Added:

- You want to use the modified script of pattern 1.
- You want to use `Michael, Ballack` and `Michael, BALLACK` as the same value.

From your replying, I could understand about that. For above case, how about the following modification? In this case, using `toUpperCase()`, both values from `Input Data` and `Assignment` are compared.

#### Modified script:

```
function checkName() {
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Input Data");
  var col1 = s1.getRange("C3:C").getValues();
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Assignment");
  var col2 = s2.getRange("C4:C").getValues();
  var found;
  for (var i=col2.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    found = false;
    for (var j=0; j<col1.length; j++) {
       if (col1[j][0].toUpperCase() == col2[i][0].toUpperCase()) {  // Modified
         found = true;
         break;
       }
    }
    if (!found) {
      s2.getRange(i+4, 1, 1, 6).clearContent();  // Modified
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what if i want to clear the contents of Column "C" and Column "G" to "BB" ?

Comment: Pattern 1 works fine! the only problem I have now is that the macro recognizes no upper and lower case letters. in my list are Full Names like "Michael, Ballack" in "Assignment" and for example "Michael, BALLACK" in "Input Data" (which is the same name) and in this case it deletes the content, but it shouldn't! Can you help me with that "upper and lower case letters" problem?

Comment: @greenster10 Thank you for replying. I apologize for my incomplete answer for your goal. I updated it. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize again.

Comment: @greenster10 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.